# Sending a Welcome email using Google Cloud Functions when the app uses Phone verification for authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a Welcome email using Google Cloud Functions, similar to what is done here:

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users

The problem is that my app uses Phone verification for authentication, we do however upload the users email and save it under the users UID in the Firebase Real time database.

Could we pull the email using the cloud function using the UID and then insert that into the javascript code? or is there another way of doing this?

Best,

Feras A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to read from the realtime database with the Firebase Admin SDK:

```
return admin.database().ref(/* path to user's email */).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.val() === null) {
    console.log("Error getting user email: user does not exist");
    return;
  }

  const email = snapshot.child("email").val();

  // Send email here
});
```

More information and examples can be found on the [Firebase Admin Auth Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) (See the example under `Authenticate with admin privileges`).